# Split shapefile to approximate area

Tags: qgis, python, clustering, splitting

I have a shapefile with multiple polygons of different sizes and want to split this shapefile to new ones trying to achieve a determined area, but without splitting any polygon.

For example: I want shapefiles of approximately 30ha, so i would enter with my base and would results in shapefiles with polygons sums of 25ha, 29ha, 35ha, etc. The most close i could get of the 30ha without splitting the polygons.

Any idea?

Comment: Are they supposed to be clustered together or completely randomly selected?

Comment: Clustered Together.